# Ranking based on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe df, here is the structure:

```
structure(list(A = c("10/18", "10/18", "10/18", "10/19", "10/19", 
"10/20", "10/18", "10/18"), B = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"2", "2"), C = c("2.3", "2.1", "0.2", "0.7", "0.4", "4.0", "3.0", 
"1.5"), D = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

The dataframe is ordered by B, A, then C descending. The values of D represent the rank of C descending based on this ordering. I removed some rows, (2,4,7), from the dataframe so now the rankings of D are no longer correct. I want to correct the ranking but unsure how. The desired output should look like:

```
structure(list(A = c("10/18", "10/18", "10/19", "10/20", "10/18"
), B = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2"), C = c("2.3", "0.2", "0.4", 
"4.0", "1.5"), D = c("1", "2", "1", "1", "1")), row.names = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've tried:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(B,A, desc(C)) %>%
  mutate(D = rank(desc(C)))
```

But this does not give me the desired output.

Update #1:
Here is the specific code I have attempted:

```
A <- c('10/18', '10/18', '10/18', '10/19', '10/19', '10/20', '10/18', '10/18')
B <- c(rep(c('1'), 6), '2', '2')
C <- c('2.3', '2.1', '0.2', '0.7', '0.4', '4.0', '3.0', '1.5')
D <- c('1','2','3', '1', '2', '1', '1', '2')
df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)

df <- df[-c(2,4,7),]  %>%
  arrange(B, A, rev(C)) %>%
  mutate(D = row_number(), .by = c(A, B))
```

Comment: Your columns B, C and D are currently character vectors, not numeric vectors. You may not get the results you expect, since these will be sorted alphabetically rather than numerically. You should convert them to numeric values. As for column A, it is not clear what this is supposed to represent or how it should be ordered.  If it is supposed to be a date, then try converting to an actual date object if you want reliable sorting.

Comment: @AllanCameron After converting B,C, and D into numeric vectors, and converting A into a date object, what would be the proper way to rank column D as I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rev(C)` in `arrange()` to order the columns by B (ascending), A (ascending), and C (descending), then reassign `D` with `row_number` in `mutate`, grouped by `A` and `B`:

```
library(dplyr)

df[-c(2,4,7),]  %>%
  arrange(B, A, rev(C)) %>%
  mutate(D = row_number(), .by = c(A, B))
  # or mutate(D = rank(desc(C)), .by = c(A, B))
```

Output:

```
      A B   C D
1 10/18 1 2.3 1
2 10/18 1 0.2 2
3 10/19 1 0.4 1
4 10/20 1 4.0 1
5 10/18 2 1.5 1
```

Comment: It seems I get an error when I try to run this. Not sure if it's because of the types of my columns.

Error in `n()`:
! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`, `filter()`,
  and `group_by()`.

Comment: Hmmm.. Are you running this exact code? Does it work on the sample data on your machine? What version of `dplyr` do you have?

Comment: Version 1.1.3. I have posted an update with the specific code I've used.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine on my computer - you may have another package interfering. Try restarting your R session and loading just dplyr?

Comment: Works like a charm now. Seems the issue was having both dplyr AND plyr loaded. Thank you.